# JAVA прервать выполнение метода если один из выполняемых методов получил exception

Tags: java, исключения

Есть метод, который вызывает 4-ре других методов

```
public void main(f47gs f47gs){      
 con.push(f47gs); \\sql запрос
 con.Quality(f47gs);\\sql запрос
                 
                     try {
                        df47.wheat(f47gs);
                        df472s.wheat(f47gs);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если в конкретном методе `con.Quality(f47gs);` я получал `SQLexception` - останавливалось выполнение `main` метода?

Comment: что значит родительского? например, исключение при выполнении con.Quality(f47gs), что должно остановиться?

Comment: @Дмитрий обновил вопрос. main метод в данном конкретном случае

Comment: вы ловите ошибку в методе верхнего уровня, потому как блок  try {
                   
                    } catch () внутри метода, если будет ексепшен то упадет и главный метод тоже, а в методе нижнего уровня поставте  throws IOException

Comment: У вас в методе `con.Quality` есть `try/catch`?

Comment: @Agzam4 да есть

Comment: @denisKrivorutchko сделал так, не помогло. так же выполняется дальше и запускает другие методы

Comment: @Drop con.Quality(Args args); у вас помечен как throws  SQLException?

Comment: @denisKrivorutchko да. решил вопрос, перенеся продолжение метода в дочерний метод и все получилось. спасибо за советы в любом случае

Comment: @Drop  выложите весь код с решением, потому как он поможет другим участникам найти ответ на етот вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это должно сработать:

```
public void main(f47gs f47gs){      
    con.push(f47gs); \\sql запрос
    try {
        con.Quality(f47gs);\\sql запрос
    } catch (SQLExceptione sqle) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        df47.wheat(f47gs);
        df472s.wheat(f47gs);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: да, я так уже делал
мне ошибку выдаёт `Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`

Comment: try { int i = 1 / 0;
} catch (Exception e) { 
/* Тк это исключение содержит ArithmeticException, возникает ошибка
 * ведь, catch (ArithmeticException e), никогда не будет выполнен*/
  } catch (ArithmeticException e1) {
/* Мертвый код*/
  }
 }  - лучше скопировать код в IDE (тк здесь не понятно)

Comment: Здесь: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html можно посмотреть, то что доминирует над `SQLException`, а это `Throwable` и `Exception`